# Text after single quotation mark not displaying

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that text after single quotes (') is not showing in the grid. You can save such a string correctly in the DB from the grid and the whole string is included in the JSON returned from the server when then grid is rendered next time, but the string is then truncated. For instance, try saving the string "Patricia's car" and only "Patricia" will display the next time the grid is rendered.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to escape quotes. In the SQL the string will be 'INSERT INTO table (values) VALUES ("Patricia's car") AND this is a error... just prepare the statment before execute or use a **sprintf** to the sentence. It will replace Patricia's by Patricia\'s

Comment: What grid? What database? What JSON? You need to (a) trace where the problem actually occurs and (b) provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Both your questions are of poor quality and are being downvoted - if this continues, you will be blocked from asking further questions

Answer (score 0):

Use \' instead of '

Use "patricia\'s car" instead of "patricia's car"